# Entity Framework Code-first Many to many relationship on the same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a slightly odd scenario here, I have one entity and one many to many table. The following tables are like so:

AssetHeader.cs

```
[Table("AssetHeader", Schema = "assets")]
public class AssetHeader
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AssetHeaderEquipment> AssetHeaders { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AssetHeaderEquipment> AssetEquipment { get; set; }
}
```

AssetHeaderEquipment.cs (many-to-many)

```
[Table("AssetHeaderEquipment", Schema = "assets")]
public class AssetHeaderEquipment
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid AssetHeaderId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid AssetEquipmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual AssetHeader AssetHeader { get; set; }
    public virtual AssetHeader AssetEquipment { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

When I attempt to create the db with code-first migration I get the following in SQL:
[image]

How do I get the code-first to generate the correct db structure, I am happy to use either attributes or fluent in dbcontext.

UPDATE:
After following the answer from Ivan Stoev the structure is as expected. However when setting the fields the following now happens...

Model attempting to save:
[image]

Actual save result:
[image]

How is the AssetEquipmentId being set to the AssetHeaderId?

I have created a very lightweight dojo project for complete code visibility. 
You can find this here:
[GitHub Code Repo](https://github.com/andy952/AssetHeaderDojo)

Comment: That's the database model I would expect from your entity design.  What's the issue?

Comment: The issue is, the two extra AssetHeader_Id and AssetHeader_Id1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the cases where EF can't automatically pair the relationships navigation properties.

Usually it can be resolved with either `InverseProperty` attributes or `Has` / `With` fluent API.  But since this type of relationship always introduces "multiple cascade paths" problem, which requires turning off cascade delete for at least one of the relationships, and that could be done only with fluent API, there is no other choice than using fluent API (which for relationships IMHO is better anyway).

The bare minimum is to configure the relationship for which you want to turn off the cascade delete. Once you do that, EF conventionally will do the rest.

For instance:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AssetHeader>()
    .HasMany(e => e.AssetEquipment)
    .WithRequired(e => e.AssetEquipment)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

The result:

```
CreateTable(
    "assets.AssetHeaderEquipment",
    c => new
        {
            AssetHeaderId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
            AssetEquipmentId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
            StartDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
            EndDate = c.DateTime(),
            Comment = c.String(maxLength: 255),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.AssetHeaderId, t.AssetEquipmentId })
    .ForeignKey("assets.AssetHeader", t => t.AssetEquipmentId)
    .ForeignKey("assets.AssetHeader", t => t.AssetHeaderId, cascadeDelete: true)
    .Index(t => t.AssetHeaderId)
    .Index(t => t.AssetEquipmentId);

CreateTable(
    "assets.AssetHeader",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

**Update** According to the problematic usage case, the correct pairings should be:

```
Collection       Inverse          FK
==========       =========        ==============
AssetHeaders     AssetEquipment   AssetEquipmentId
AssetEquipment   AssetHeader      AssetHeaderId
```

Hence remove the misleading `ForeignKey` attributes and use the following fully explicit fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AssetHeader>()
    .HasMany(e => e.AssetHeaders)
    .WithRequired(e => e.AssetEquipment)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.AssetEquipmentId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<AssetHeader>()
    .HasMany(e => e.AssetEquipment)
    .WithRequired(e => e.AssetHeader)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.AssetHeaderId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: Sorry, still having issues actually after testing it further... Changes added in main question

Comment: No problem. First make sure I mapped the pairs correctly. Currently the `AssetHeaderEquipment.AssetEquipment` is mapped to `AssetHeader.AssetEquipment` collection, but you might want to map it to `AssetHeader.AssetHeaders` collection instead (it depends what `AssetHeaders` collection means) by changing `.HasMany(e => e.AssetEquipment)` to `.HasMany(e => e.AssetHeaders)`. Second, please post the *code* which reproduces the new issue rather than screenshots, because I can't reproduce with simple test, and there might be something specific in your case.

Comment: I removed the AssetHeaders collection as I don't actually need that for now. My migration script is the same as yours above, but it is still saving incorrectly. I will try and get a very simple test app running to give you a better picture...

Comment: I have created a very lightweight project, you can find this here: https://github.com/andy952/AssetHeaderDojo

Comment: Ok, this what I meant by correctly pairing the navigation properties. See the update, it works correctly with your sample project scenario.